# How to blur a part of a canvas element?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, html5-canvas

How can I blur a part of my canvas element?

I'm using a JavaScript 3D Library which is called three.js. Three.js is a Library which makes WebGL simpler. They provide some blur and the depth of field examples there, but I think these are post processing effects which I'm not familiar with. Is there an "easy" way to blur for example 60px from top of a canvas element?

Three.js:
http://threejs.org/

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can clone your canvas element and add a blur effect to the css.

```
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
clone = background.cloneNode("canvas");
document.getElementById("blurred").appendChild(clone);
```

Something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/wilt/sE4Fv/653/)**